# why isn't there redis-check-dump --fix, or how can I fix a corrupted dump.rdb?

Tags: redis

I got a corrupted dump.rdb after an unexpected power off. And redis-server can't start anymore, with error: `Short read or OOM loading DB. Unrecoverable error`.
I tried `redis-check-dump` on my dump.rdb, it says: `Total unprocessable opcodes: 49`. But how can I fix them?